# Atlas generation: get attributes of all features from the current view

Tags: qgis, expression, atlas

I would like to show the attributes of every feature in the current view of the atlas.

The background: On every page of the atlas is a map with some markers. The markers have got numbers and a text description. I would like to show the text description of the markers (which are in the current view) in a text field on top of the map.

[image]

Comment: Is a table of the text fields acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a lot easier if you could show the data in a table format.

Add to the markers layer attribute table and extra column that relates to the coverage layer your using for the atlas generation.  You can then insert the attribute table into the print composer and, using an expression, limit which records are shown for that particular map. The atlas will then do all the work updating the table with the information relating to that particular atlas view.

Comment: Its working fine so far, but not exactly what I was looking for. Now I have a table with 2 collums: Number and Description. But the number should be a black dot with the number inside. I can't see any way to get to this.

Comment: OK. So what your looking for is more like a legend with the number icon on the left and a description on the right.  I think this can be done (as long as your descriptions aren't too long). If your number icons are stylised points then you could change the label to the description. Then when you insert the legend into the map composer you'll get your styled points along with the description.  Use the "Wrap text on" to format.  This might be a little back and forth to get it right but insert periods in strategic locations will make it look good. (the periods disapear on wrap so don't worry)